# Warning: Prop `id` did not match. Server in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to get rid of a warning in my project:

```
react-dom.development.js?61bb:67 Warning: Prop `id` did not match. Server: "t4j6jv-aria" Client: "v0lutu9-aria"
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what's causing the problem, any help or help appreciated.
This is what line 60 looks at in CasinoList.tsx:

[image]

this is line #60:

[image]

Some Code prior to line 60:

```
interface IProps {
  country: string;
  flag: string;
  casinoComments: {
    id: number;
    commentId: number;
    content: string;
    created: string;
    likes: number;
    author: string;
  };
}

interface IState {
  slug: String;
  selectedLanguage: String;
  visible: Boolean;
  showList: Boolean;
  highlightedHobby: Boolean;
  isMobile: Boolean;
  tagItems: Array<tagItems>;
  activeTag: String;
  tagId: Number;
}

interface tagItems {
  id: number;
  label: String;
  name: String;
  state: Boolean;
}

export default class FeaturedCasinos extends React.Component<
  IProps,
  IState,
  { country: String; flag: String }
> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: We'll actually need to see what's in the render part of the component. Also, are you using any component library? Please provide a [mre].